# Superclass method with argument list<superclass> used with specialized lists

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl

I am new to C++ and I am trying to develop a 2D simulation on which every represented element is a subclass of Point. I have several a list for each subclass (listA, listB...).

I am trying to implement a function that finds the closest point to the current point, for example, which B instance is the closest to the current A instance. It makes sense to me to put this function in the Point class since it may be used by each subclass, but since my program uses lists of specialized items (`std::list<A>` instead of `std::list<Point>`), I get an error with the following code:

```
class Point 
{
    Point* findClosest(std::list<Point*>&);
};

class A : public Point
{
    void update(std::list<B*>&);
};

class B : public Point
{
};

void A::update(std::list<B*>& blist)
{
    B* closest = this->findClosest(blist); //bug
    // do something...
}
```

Error message:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘A::findClosest(std::__cxx11::list<A*>&)’`

`note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::list<A*>’ to ‘std::__cxx11::list<Point*, std::allocator<Point*> >&’`

If I were using lists of Point instead of lists of specialized elements, it would work, but I would be forced to cast the elements of these lists each time I need to use a method specific to the class (like `update()` for class A).

Is there any way that my list of A can be interpreted as a list of Point?

Thank for help!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as required here please?

Comment: Wait---you're trying to pass in a list of `B*`s but you're expecting an `A*` return value? How would that work?

Comment: @Brian Functions don't have to return the same thing that they take as arguments. In this case, the function should determine _"which B instance is the closest to the current A instance"_ (direct quote from the question).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If the function should determine which B instance is closest to the current A instance, then it should return a B instance, right? I really don't understand what's going on here...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes you are right I made a mistake in the question, the function should return a B pointer, I have edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it this way because `list<B*>` does not inherit from `list<Point*>`.

In your case you will probably have to work by using only `list<Point*>` and instantiating each `Point` as either `A` or `B`: let virtual functions of `Point` do the separation for you. Though, in general, I do not recommend such design for various reasons (it will have slow runtime due usage of too many allocations and deallocations which will cause memory fragmentation problems; also there will be too many calls for virtual functions; don't forget memory leaks in case you forgot to deallocate)

If you really want to pass `list<B*>` for arbitrary classes then you will have to work with templates, but I believe those are a bit too early for you.

```
class Point 
{
    template<class T>
    Point* findClosest(std::list<T*>&)
    {
      // write implementation here in .h; not in .cpp
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll go with the template solution then! But if I do this, there are no checks that the objects contained in the given list are instances of subclasses of Point...

Comment: Indeed, currently there are no ways to demand from user that the classes have to derive from Point; In C++20 they are adding Concepts TS which solves the problem.

With the template case you should be careful as templates and their syntax is complicated and unforgiving: debugging and ensuring that the code compiles can be very difficult.

Aside from that, I'd recommend not using pointers (unless you really need them - save them for complicated structures) - use `std::list<T>` instead of `std::list<T*>`; and I wouldn't use list at all, better use `std::vector<T>` or `std::map<key,T>`.